# return the first word from square bracket using regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a file which contain

```
[[ abstraction, verb.cognition:abstract,+ ]]
```

I want to remove the square bracket and want to keep the word `abstraction` from this bracket. So the output should be -

```
abstraction
```

I have tried -

```
import re

with open('test.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        rx = re.compile(r'\[[^][]*]')  string
        while rx.search(line):
            line = rx.sub('',line)                     
            s = line.strip()
            print(s)
```

which shows `[]` only square bracket.Is there ay way to do this? please help .

Comment: If the format doesn't change, simple string formatting would do: `s.split(',')[0].lstrip('[ ')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `re.search`

**Ex:**

```
s = "[[ abstraction, verb.cognition:abstract,+ ]]"
m = re.search("\[\[(.*?)\,.*", s)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
```

**Output:**

```
 abstraction
```

Comment: It works but In my file there are more lines like - `entity , [[ abstraction, verb.cognition:abstract,+ ]] , physical_entity` . I also want to print these lines `entity 
abstraction
physical_entity` .
I have tried your code,it shows `abstraction` which is correct . But when I want to  print others line how can i do that?

Comment: @jahan. That would mean a totally different requirement and regex.

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need to worry about the brackets, if your file only contains that, you only need to match the first word.

```
import re
t = "[[ abstraction, verb.cognition:abstract,+ ]] "

match = re.search(r"\b([^,]+)\b", t)
# prints False when no match is found
print(match is not None and match.group(0))
# abstraction
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this too,

```
line="""[[ abstraction, verb.cognition:abstract,+ ]] rewq [[ abs, verb.cognition:abstract,+ ]] fdsaf [[ abstraction, verb.cfdsa,+ ]] """
rx = re.compile(r'\[\[[^][]*]]')
line = rx.sub(lambda m: '' if m.group(0).find("abstraction")== -1 else "abstraction", line)                     
s = line.strip()
print(s)
```

Output is

```
abstraction rewq  fdsaf abstraction
```